# Need to recover information from a reformatted external drive

Tags: permission

I just purchased my first Mac, a MacPro.

I have been using the Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex external drive, but with my new MacPro I cannot add any new folders. I checked the Sharing Permission and it states that "You can only read".  In order to change my permissions, I reformatted the drive.

I did not realize it would wipe my drive clean.  Can I recover the information in the drive.

Answer (score 1):

PhotoRec is a free program that I've used that may help you recover files. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

However, some information may not be recoverable no matter what you use, such as folder structures. Whatever you do, don't save any new files to the drive, and probably leave it off unless you are recovering. If you are uncomfortable, there are lots of places that will do data recovery for you.

You probably already know that you were unable to write to your external drive if it was formatted with NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

Try EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard for Mac 10.10 I had lost a drive with all my photos - and had deleted from a old drive that I reformatted. I was able to pull them from that old drive using this program, it has a 2gb recovery trial that will allow you to test it before you buy it.